# CosmoDB Connection Timeout

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-api-apps, azure-app-service-plans

I'm running our NodeJS app on the free tier of the Azure API app service. It consistently times out when trying to connect to our instance of Cosmo DB. We don't experience any issues when running our NodeJS app locally, it only happens when being run in the app service. This is the error that we get:

```
MongoDB connection error: { [MongoError: connection 1 to documents.azure.com:10255 timed out]
name: 'MongoError',
message: 'connection 1 to documents.azure.com:10255 timed out' }
```

I've confirmed the connection string is correct and tried updating the IP address whitelist for CosmoDB.

Comment: hi, how did you solve this?

Comment: @Cocuba Never found a solution unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Ran into a similar issue

I found the following article on setting this up
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/create-mongodb-nodejs

long story short I had to add `&sslverifycertificate=false` to the end of the connection string

Comment: Tried it with that parameter and still no luck when running it from the app service. It continues to work when running locally.

Answer (score 0):

Try Appending these 2 in the end

```
&maxIdleTimeMS=1500000&connect=direct
```

Comment: Using direct connect seems to be advised by Azure.

However setting the maxIdleTime that high might cause EOF errors since the azure LB has a default timeout of 4 minutes: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/cosmos-db/concepts-limits#mongodb-api-specific-limits